# Batch edit in OpenRefine

Tags: openrefine

So, I have a bunch of .csv files which need cleaning. They all need to go through the same steps, so I've extracted OpenRefine's operation history in order to apply it to other ones.

I could open each file one by one in OpenRefine and apply the extracted JSON history. But there are a lot of files...

Also, I don't have enough memory to open them all at once in OpenRefine (multiple selecting when opening the files).

Is there any way I could edit them all or automatically using that JSON I extracted from OpenRefine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what we created [BatchRefine](https://github.com/fusepoolP3/p3-batchrefine) for, the README should be pretty much self-explanatory. If not, let me know.

I just recently converted 4 million CSV records to RDF using BatchRefine, took me less than 10 minutes on my MacBook Pro.

I execute BatchRefine with this simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./input/*.tsv
do
  filename=$(basename "$file")

  if [ ! -f "target/"$filename"-transformed" ]
  then
    echo Processing $filename...
    curl -XPOST -H 'Accept: text/turtle' -H 'Content-Type:text/csv' --data-binary "@"$file -o "target/"$filename"-transformed" 'localhost:8310/?refinejson=http://localhost:8000/bar-config.json'

  else
    echo Found "target/"$filename"-transformed", skipping $file
  fi
done;
```

Note that you need to adjust the `Accept`header in the script, I guess you want CSV as output again, not RDF.

Comment: What were the size of csv file?

Comment: The original CSV was around 1GB

Answer (score 1):

You can automate some OpenRefine operations using one of the existing libraries:

- [python](https://github.com/PaulMakepeace/refine-client-py/)
- [An other python library](https://github.com/maxogden/refine-python)
- [ruby](https://github.com/maxogden/refine-ruby)
- [javascript - nodejs](https://github.com/pm5/node-openrefine)